# css styling in knockout js for dynamic binding

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

Here is my code:

```html
<div data-bind="template:{name:'person-template',foreach:$data[1],afterrender:sample}">

This will create the 6 divs and 6 anchors dynamically using template.
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
<div id="uniqueid">
</div>
<a style="border-left-width:1px">
</a>
</script>
```

I have a set of 6 divs and 6 anchors respectively. I tried `float:left` , 
`display:block` and other types of styling, but I'm not sure how to display the six blocks continuously, with each block containing a div and an anchor.

Comment: You probably want to put a `div` around the contents of your template, and use `display: flex` on the div with the foreach binding.

Comment: Second previous comment. - Some feedback on the question: you'll get better response if you create an actual [mcve]. Your question has nothing to do with KO, so I recommend removing that, including *rendered* final markdown, including your current css. Also: let us know why you tag "html5" and "css3", because there's nothing specific to those techs in your post currently. Finally, please be precise about the expected outcome: if you want things to take up full width then flexbox or display:table are relevant, otherwise maybe less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate through the data and then reference each iteration within the template as $data.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtalley/2o3hfvfd/6/

The view...

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'person-template', foreach: data, afterrender: sample}">

<!-- This will create the 6 divs and 6 anchors dynamically using template. -->
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
  <div id="uniqueid" />
  <a style="border-left-width:1px" data-bind="attr: { href: $data.url }, text:   $data.text" />
</script>
```

and the viewmodel...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.data = ko.observableArray([
        {
        text: 'Google',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
      },
      {
        text: 'Yahoo',
        url: 'http://www.yahoo.com'
      },
      {
        text: 'New York Times',
        url: 'http://www.nytimes.com'
      },
      {
        text: 'Reddit',
        url: 'http://www.reddit.com'
      },
      {
        text: 'JS Fiddle',
        url: 'http://www.jsfiddle.net'
      },
      {
        text: 'Stackoverflow',
        url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
      }
    ]);

    self.sample = function(){};
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

});
```